# How to have a dynamic token for facebook using login and password only?

Tags: facebook, proxy, xmpp, token, google-talk

I'm working on proxy XMPP that listen on port 5222 for Gtalk and I need token to change the request of users and sent it to the server that's why I use this url:

```
String url = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?" +
                "accountType=GOOGLE&Email=" + user + "&Passwd=" +
                password + "&service=mail";
```

which give me token and I can work. But I need to do the same thing for facebook but I can't find an url that does the same thing, I found this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/client_code?access_token=...&client_secret=...&redirect_uri=...&client_id=...
```

But there are many parameters that I don't have like redirect_uri it's for my web service, but I don't have a web service, I just need it for a proxy... Someone can help me to have
a dynamic token for facebook using only login and password?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Chat API allows to use standard [DIGEST-MD5](http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/SASLandDIGEST-MD5) authentication

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Ok, but I need to make a PLAIN authentication. Is that possible?
I already seen this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat?locale=fr_FR#plainauth
But I'm working on Java Android, that's why I don't have all parameters I'm talkin about in my first post.